# Generate <input type="search" /> using Play! framework

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm using the Play Framework. I want to use the [HTML5 input type 'search'](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.search.html#input.search.attrs.type). So, I want to output:

```
<input type="search" />
```

I've tried:

```
@inputText(field = myForm("myField"), 'type -> "search")
```

but it still kept the type="input"

Comment: Is that a typo, or is it in your code? `'type -> ...` Missing end quote.

Comment: @Dylan: that's not a mistake: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaFormHelpers

Comment: Oh right I forgot about "symbols" in scala

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the method `inputText` represents an HTML input text (see the source code [here](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/inputText.scala.html)).

You have to define your own template to define the input of type `search`. Take a look at the [Play documentation](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.2/JavaFormHelpers).

```
@helper.input(myForm("myField")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="search" name="@name" id="@id" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Most probably your search field will not use many typical things from common form element (like `constraints` or `error` messages) so you can just use plain HTML to insert it, and add field's value in the proper attribute (if required at all):

```
<input type="search" name="myField" value="@myForm("myField").value" />
```

If it's just a search form (with this only field) you even don't need to wrap it with the `Form` class

(of course Nico's suggest is advisable in more sophisticated scenarios)

Answer (score 0):

Some helpers you're looking for are avalaible in a play 2 module. The html5 input helpers are not in the core part of the framework because play authors want to keep it light.
Here is the module page on github : https://github.com/loicdescotte/Play2-HTML5Tags